# Implement this round function into this bit of code

Tags: vb.net, format, rounding

Ok, so I am designing this math code, it is for quadratic equation,

I have a function which the user defines the round digit, and it works here is the example of this:

```
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Second Root, (Root2) = {0:F" & decimalPlace & "}", x2))
```

However I tried to implement it into this bit of code:

```
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Second Root, (Root2) = {{0}{1}" & decimalPlace & "}", x2 & " - ", complexRoot & "i"))
```

This does not work however this works but the round function is not implemented, I was wondering if someone can help me out, thank you

```
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Second Root, (Root2) = {0}{1}", x2 & " - ", complexRoot & "i"))
```

Comment: Keep the parameters of Format for variables only: String.Format("Second Root, (Root2) = {0:F" & decimalPlace & "} - {1:F" & decimalPlace & "}i", x2, complexRoot)

Comment: @the_lotus I'm sorry if you have misunderstood but I especially want the {0:F, x1 value to be just x1, as it will be 0 and the complex number be rounded to the parameter of "decimalPlace"

Comment: also would you be able to explain to me why we need these {0:F's and what they are called, I've always used them but don't understand the logic behind them, thank you

Comment: The {0} and {1} are placeholders in the string that refer to the comma delimited variables following the string. The portion of the place holder following the colon is a Format String. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: A more modern way to deal with this is the Interpolated String. It starts with a $ preceding the first ". In braces you can insert variables in place in the string. You can still use formatting following a colon the same as String.Format.